# Move Album from Lightroom CC to Lightroom Classic

Tags: lightroom, software, photo-editing, photo-management

I've been using Lightroom CC for a while now, but recently I started using Lightroom Classic as well. I know how to sync all photos from Lightroom CC with Lightroom Classic, but I'd like to add all the photos from just a single album in Lightroom CC to Lightroom Classic. Is this possible? If it is, could someone explain to me how to do it?

Comment: Are you looking to export an album of 'finished' photos not meant for further editing, or shifting the original files [possibly with editing meta-data] from LR-CC to LR-Classic?

Answer (score 1):

According to [these guys](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2525126) you need to

> ... mark (Cmd/Ctrl + A) them in Lr CC, then right click and choose "Save To" - in the dialog choose the file format (Original and Settings) and chose location. Then add the local files to your Lr CC desktop catalog

if you want to move an actual set of images to your local computer.